# cannot set default value for drop down

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui-angular2

This is my kendo drop down for Angular 2:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist 
[defaultItem]="defaultItem"
[data] = "getYears"
[textField]="'YearText'"
[valueField]="'YearValue'"
[(ngModel)] = "selectedYear"
>
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

**clearFilters()** is my method which gets executed when i click clear on UI.

```
private selectedYear : Year = { YearText: "Select...", YearValue: null };

clearFilters(): void {
  this.selectedYear = { YearText: "Select...", YearValue: null };         
}
```

but when i click clear, it won't set itself to select? what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that will be fixed in an upcoming release, in the mean time you can set `[valuePrimitive]="true"`, however it is not supposed to work this way - just a temporary workaround.